# Azure linux VM lose host name and becomes unreachable

Tags: azure, centos, virtual-machine

After a size upgrade I did to my CentOS VM in azure, from size A3 to A4, I lost VM's host name & SSH Certificate Thumbprint (in azure portal shows - ) and I cannot login with ssh and generally my VM does not operate - in fact this virtual machine is a linux web server with WHM-cpanel Web Host management system. None of my web sites do not operate, neither whm, cpanel and ssh login!
 I don't know if this host name & ssh certificate lost is the problem or this is an aftereffect of another VM's issue.
This is not the first time I have faced this issue, the other times I lost my VM and forced to re-created.
So has anyone encountered this issue again, could you please help?
Thanks in advance, 
George

Comment: that's strange, do you have the public ip of the VM, may be share a screenshot with us (fudge the sensitive details)

Comment: Because it was a production machine and I did not have any answers from Microsoft support or other I deleted it and re-created it. Thanks anyway.